# jQuery Show Hide WC Chekout Field if Number Field Value 0

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the HTML table I need to conditionally hide the fee row if the value is 0 which uses a number woocommerce_form_field type number.

```js
$('.donation_amount').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $('.fee th').hide();
  } else {
    $('.fee th').show();
  }
}).keyup();
```

```html
<input type="number" class="input-text " name="donation_amount" id="donation_amount" placeholder="" value="">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="fee">
      <th>Amount</th>
      <td>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0.00</bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update :** This is what i have tried so far :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 val = $('input#donation_amount').val();

  if (val == "0") {

    $('.fee').hide();
    $( 'tr').removeClass('fee');
    $('.fee').css("display", "none");
//  } else {
//    $('.fee').show();
  }

   amount = $('#woocommerce-Price-amount').val();

  if (amount == "0.00") {

    $('.fee').hide();
    $( 'tr').removeClass('fee');
    $('.fee').css("display", "none");
//  } else {
//    $('.fee').show();
  }

     num = $('.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol').val();

  if (num == "0.00") {

    $('.fee').hide();
    $( 'tr').removeClass('fee');
    $('.fee').css("display", "none");
//  } else {
//    $('.fee').show();
  }

    amount = $('#donation-amount').val();

  if (amount == "0.00") {

    $('.fee').hide();
    $( 'tr').removeClass('fee');
    $('.fee').css("display", "none");
//  } else {
//    $('.fee').show();
  }

  $('#donation_amount').on('keyup change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0 ) {

      $('.fee').hide();
      $( "tr" ).removeClass( "fee" );
  }
});

});
```

I've tried using the div id for the number field #donation_amount and the value for the price currency field but neither works with any of the 3 methods i have tested.

Comment: You do not have anything that has a .val() in the HTML you presented. A table does not have a val. Please right click on the thing that has the value and post the HTML from the inspect

Comment: Hi , do you mean by value of `<bdi>` tag i.e : 0.00 ?

Comment: Also please use toggle: `$('.fee th').toggle(some statement that is true (truthy) or false (falsy));`

Comment: Updated with the HTML for the number field.

Comment: Isn't it the whole row - `.fee`, rather than `.fee th` - that needs to be hidden?

Comment: yes the entire row needs to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jQuery code,

```
jQuery( '#donation_amount' ).on( 'keyup', function () {
    if ( jQuery(this).val() == 0 ) {
        $( '.fee' ).hide();
    } else {
        $( '.fee' ).show();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, tried but doesn't work. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple function that gets the value from the input and uses that value to determine whether or not to show or hide the `.fee` row with jQuery's [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method:

```
function updateFeeDisplay () {
  const value =  Number($('#donation_amount').val()) || 0;

  $('.fee').toggle(value > 0);
}

$('#donation_amount').on('change keyup', updateFeeDisplay);

updateFeeDisplay();
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/t7nrsv6p/) is an example fidde.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Any idea how to use that with the wc_enqueue_js function

Comment: @BrettStack1: I believe you would just wrap it in quotes to make it a string and then pass it to that function, as in `wc_enqueue_js( ' {copied_code_from_post}' );`.

Comment: No that doesn't work when i test it. I just need to work out how to load this js now.

Comment: @BrettStack1 Is the table loaded on the page asynchronously? I would add a `console.log` before the event binding. Something like `console.log($('#donation_amount').length);`. If the `length` is `0`, then we know we need to delegate the event handler.

Comment: Its loaded by the default on the WooCommerce checkout page.

Comment: How do i add the extra code?